# How to replace first occurrence of character in a string?

Tags: python, string

Given string as:

```
s = "Python is programming language"
```

In this, I want to replace 2nd occurrence of `'n'` with any character, let's say `'o'`. The expected string would be:

```
"Python is programmiog language"
```

How to do this in python? Can I do it using `replace` function only? or any other way to do that?

Answer (score 5):

You need to call [`str.replace()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.replace) with *`maxreplace`* parameter. For just replacing the first character in the string, you need to pass `maxreplace` as `1`. For example:

```
>>> s = "Python is programming language"
>>> s.replace('n', 'o', 1)
'Pythoo is programming language'
#     ^ Here first "n" is replaced with "o"
```

From the [`str.replace` document](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.replace):

> **`string.replace(s, old, new[, maxreplace])`**
>
> Return a copy of string `s` with all occurrences of substring old replaced by `new`. **If the optional argument `maxreplace` is given, the first maxreplace occurrences are replaced.**